# Is 1 - Dirichlet variable also a Dirichlet?

Tags: probability, dirichlet-distribution

Just a simple question regarding the properties of Dirichlet distribution:

Suppose $(X_1, \ldots, X_K) \sim Dir(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_K)$, can we express the distribution for $(1-X_1, \ldots, 1-X_K)$ in terms $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_K$?

I'm thinking about the follow form but not 100% sure:

$(1-X_1, \ldots, 1-X_K) \sim Dir(\sum_i\alpha_i-\alpha_1, \ldots, \sum_i\alpha_i-\alpha_K)$?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^K (1-X_i)$ is not equal to $1$ if $K\neq2$ so  $(1-X_1,\ldots,1-X_K)$ cannot be Dirichlet. Is this the answer or were you thinking about some scaling?   You seem to be using $k$ and $K$ to denote the same thing, could you fix that?

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! Will there still be a closed form expression for $(1- X_1,\ldots,1-X_K)$? Will $(1- KX_1,\ldots,1-KX_K) \sim Dir(\sum_i\alpha_i-K\alpha_1,\ldots,\sum_i\alpha_i-K\alpha_K)$ because $\sum_{i=1}^K(1-KX_i)=1$?

Comment: How did this question arise? It doesn't seem that such distribution could describe any meaningful real-life phenomenon.

Comment: The question arises in deriving closed form expectation of Bernouli likelihood $L=\sum_jY\log(X_j)+(1-Y)\log(1-X_j)$, where $Y$ is a $K\times1$ observed vector and the $K\times1$ rate vector $X_j$ for component $j$ is assumed to have a Dirichlet prior. The expectation of $L$ requires the closed form expression of the expectation of $\log(1-X_j)$.